# Is there a way to stop backface-visibility:hidden during transitions on safari?

Tags: safari, css-transitions

Transitions are great! When used with a **Capable Browser**, until recently i thought that term included Chrome, Firefox and Safari... Firefox and Safari have just been letting the side down!

I am attempting a fairly complex group of animations involving purely transitions and fixed backgrounds. And in Chrome everything is gravy, I apply the transitions and move elements within a parent container that has a `background-image` set and a `background-attachment` of fixed.

From what i've observed;
in safari whenever any sorts of transitions occur backface-visibility:hidden is attached to all elements on the page or certainly a number of ancestors or the target element.

`backface-visibility:hidden;` has a fairly undocumented issue when used in conjunction with `background-attatchment:fixed;` it will remove the `background-image` that is being fixed form view see here.

So therefore when any transitions occur anywhere on the page that involve opacity or 3d transforming my image flickers our and back in again when safari applys the `backface-visibility` effect.

Does anyone know a way around this issue?
Its rather annoying, and as I doubt apple will be updating for a while I'm hoping theres a solution.